# How to pass data between two viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development as well as Obj-C, so if this happens to be a duplicate of a question (I've seen some through Googling), please forgive me. I do have an adequate handle on C, C++, and C#, so the basic concepts I understand.

What I'm trying to develop is an equation calculator - that is, a Master-Detail Application where the equation is selected and then data is put into the appropriate boxes and calculated.

Now, what I am wondering is how to pass data through the view controllers - that is, how is it that for example, if Equation 1 is selected as opposed to Equation 2, that the detail view knows to perform the appropriate calculation on the data? Also, as some equations are two variables whereas some are multivariate, I need to use that data to show/hide UITextFields.

Is there a bool function or instance that returns a truth value depending on which cell is selected? How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your ViewControllerB.h

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *isSomethingEnabled;
```

In yout VC1,

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

But to pass back data to ViewController1 you need to use delegate

I guess youare not only new to Objective-C but also new to stack overflow

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

just see at the left side of your question there are lots of question related to your

Comment: Makes sense. I only need to pass data down the chain, so no need for AppDelegate involvement. To answer your second premise; I'm not new here - of what I could find for a prior search and the looking I did before posting, I did not find that question. I found other answers, but others seemed to be at a level of involvement which was not concurrent with my current understanding of Obj-C.

Comment: It it helped then do mark it as answer and upvotes are always welcome :) ... Did it solved your problem or do u need more help ?

Comment: It appears to have...I'm still fighting the endless war with the rest of Objective-C and Xcode in the meantime

Comment: @user2419180 : believe me it took me nearly year to understand Objective-c ... but today i love it :-) .. it will take time but one day u will say u will love this language ... all the best