# How to change the property of a parent class from the child class?

Tags: ios, properties

I am working with an iPhone app in Xcode.
I have 2 classes that are view controllers. One parent and one child class. The parent class is called "RaknaLista" and the child class is called "P_Format".

In P_Format you can change 2 strings that shows in 2 labels (valdBreddLabel & valdHojdLabel). When you press save and go back to RaknaLista I want the values to be shown in a TextView called "minTrycksaktext" there but it do not work, it only shows (null) in the place for the values.
Can someone help me please and say what Im doing wrong?

RaknaLista.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RaknaLista : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain)  IBOutlet UITextView *minTrycksaktext;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *format_Bredd;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *format_Hojd;

@end
```

RaknaLista.m:

```
#import "RaknaLista.h"


@interface RaknaLista ()

@end

@implementation RaknaLista

@synthesize format_Bredd,format_Hojd;
@synthesize minTrycksaktext;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    minTrycksaktext.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Format: \n\nBredd: %@ \nHöjd: %@ \n", format_Bredd, format_Hojd];

}
```

P_Format.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RaknaLista.h"

@interface P_Format : RaknaLista <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *valdBreddLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *valdHojdLabel;

-(IBAction)sparaPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

P_Format.m

```
#import "P_Format.h"

@interface P_Format ()

@end

@implementation P_Format

@synthesize valdBreddLabel;
@synthesize valdHojdLabel;


-(IBAction)sparaPressed:(id)sender{

RaknaLista *raknalista = [[RaknaLista alloc]init];

raknalista.format_Bredd = valdBreddLabel.text;
raknalista.format_Hojd = valdHojdLabel.text;

}


@end
```

Comment: You should really look at naming convetion for ios. Using what look likes Swedish in your code is not good practice for any code. it is just a tip.

Comment: Are you using ARC? You're using `assign` and `retain` which are pre-ARC memory qualifiers, so that makes me think you're not using ARC. But you don't have any `release` statements so, if you're using ARC you'd be leaking. I want to answer the question, but would like to know whether you're using ARC or not.

Comment: Are you using ARC? You're using `assign` and `retain` which are pre-ARC memory qualifiers, so that makes me think you're not using ARC. But you don't have any `release` statements so, if you're using ARC you'd be leaking. Also, are you using storyboards or NIBs? Without providing answers to these questions, it's hard for people to recommend the necessary corrections to your code.

Comment: I am not using ARC but I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here. For example, you have a method

   ```
   -(IBAction)sparaPressed:(id)sender{

       RaknaLista *raknalista = [[RaknaLista alloc]init];

       raknalista.format_Bredd = valdBreddLabel.text;
       raknalista.format_Hojd = valdHojdLabel.text;
   }
   ```

   That doesn't really make sense. You're creating a new instance of `RaknaLista`, setting `format_Bredd` and `format_Hojd`, but then letting the `raknalista` fall out of scope thereby discarding the values you just saved.
2. It doesn't really make sense to make `P_Format` be a subclass of `RaknaLista`. If these are two distinct view controllers, they each should be subclasses of `UIViewController`, not one being a subclass of the other. Don't confuse the sequence that view controllers are presented with the class hierarchy.
3. If you want `P_Format` to update `RaknaLista` you should employ a delegate-protocol pattern.

   First, in `P_Format.h`, you'd

   - make it a `UIViewController` subclass;
   - define a protocol (i.e. what is the method name that `P_Format` will call when it want to update `RaknaLista`); and
   - define a `delegate` (this will be a pointer to the `RaknaLista` object).

   Thus, `P_Format.h` would look like:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @protocol P_FormatDelegate <NSObject>

   - (void)updateBredd:(NSString *)bredd hojd:(NSString *)hojd;

   @end

   @interface P_Format : UIViewController

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *valdBreddLabel;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *valdHojdLabel;

   @property (nonatomic, assign) id<P_FormatDelegate> delegate;

   -(IBAction)sparaPressed:(id)sender;

   @end
   ```

   Thus RaknaLista.h should be defined as conforming to `P_FormatDelegate`:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "P_Format.h"

   @interface RaknaLista : UIViewController <P_FormatDelegate>

   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *minTrycksaktext;

   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *format_Bredd;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *format_Hojd;

   @end
   ```

   Now, when `RaknaLista` wants to present `P_Format`, you'd do it like you are now, but also make sure to set the `delegate` property of `P_Format` to reference the `RaknaLista` instance. For example, when `RaknaLista.m` wants to transition to `P_Format`, assuming you were using NIBs and were presenting `P_Format` modally, you'd do something like:

   ```
   - (void)presentPFormat
   {
       P_Format *controller = [[P_Format alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
       controller.delegate = self;
       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

       [controller release];   // this is not needed in ARC
   }
   ```

   Also, `RaknaLista.m` has to implement that method defined by the `P_FormatDelegate` protocol that will allow `P_Format` to update `format_Bredd` and `format_Hojd`:

   ```
   - (void)updateBredd:(NSString *)bredd hojd:(NSString *)hojd
   {
       self.format_Bredd = bredd;
       self.format_Hojd  = hojd;
   }
   ```

   Finally, when `P_Format` wants to update the height (`hojd`) and width (`bredd`) properties in `RaknaLista` it will invoke the `updateBredd:hojd:` method defined by the `P_FormatDelegate` protocol. And it will call that method using the `delegate` property that `RaknaLista` set before presenting the `P_Format` view controller:

   ```
   - (IBAction)sparaPressed:(id)sender{

       [self.delegate updateBredd:self.valdBreddLabel.text hojd:self.valdHojdLabel.text];
   }
   ```

I know that looks like a lot, but it's a pattern with which you really should become familiar, because it's very common in Cocoa Touch development. The protocol is the interface by which the "child" updates the "parent". The "child" will have a `delegate` property (so it knows upon which object to call that method defined in the protocol).

By the way, I'm using your "parent" and child" terminology, but I'd suggest you refrain from those terms when talking about view controllers, because those terms actually imply a very special meaning in Cocoa Touch, specifically the advanced topic of custom container view controllers (aka view controller containment). I'm assuming you're not doing that here, and I used the terms just to be consistent with your question, but you should refrain from "parent" and "child" controller terminology, unless doing containment.

Finally, I agree with others that the names of these classes is not ideal (but I refrained from changing them for fear of having already thrown too much at you). But generally, I would have suggested replacing `RaknaLista` with something like `RaknaViewController` and `P_Format` with `DetailsViewController` or something like that. Likewise, `format_Bredd` should probably just be `bredd`, and `format_Hojd` would be just `hojd`. See the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) for more information on naming conventions.

See the Apple documentation on [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Protocol.html) and [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html), which provide links to lots of other wonderful documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If let's say this is your parent class

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *items;

@end
```

and what you need is to set items from a child class, let's say

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController : ParentViewController

@end
```

then you should put this down in the parent class

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController ()

@end

@implementation ParentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _items = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items {
    _items = items;
}
```

and in the child class, implement the following method

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@implementation ChildViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items {

    [super setItems:items];
    // Write any custom code

}
```

Answer (score -1):

look at creating a protocol [Working with protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

or something like this [Passing data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529270/how-to-pass-data-between-two-viewcontrollers)

Answer (score -1):

This was the best and easiest way I found to pass data between view-controllers:

http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/08/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-objective-c.html